# How to list distinct sqlite queryset in django

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I'm trying to get all unique values of a certain field of a Django model.
Unfortunately sqlite doesn't support DISTINCT on fields so the following didn't work

```
dates = Invoices.objects.distinct('invoice_date')
```

so I've tried this

```
dates = Invoices.objects.values_list('invoice_date').distinct()
```

what looked good on first sight because `dates.count()` returns the amount of unique values.
However `len(dates)` still returns the total number of dates and when I transform it into a list (to be able to build a JSON response) via `list(dates)` I end up with all dates :/

How can get that list of uniques values?
Or is it impossible with sqlite?

Comment: Thanks, this has revealed I missed an order_by('invoice_date') which causes the desired result (though I've no idea why order_by is necessary here)

Answer (score 0):

you can use **set** to get the unique (differents) values.

```
dates = set(Invoices.objects.values_list('invoice_date'))
```

Comment: many thanks – set causes the desired result!

Additionally I've wrapped the set() with a list() but due to set there are only unique values left :-)